# linking .dylib via LDFLAGS using clang/LLVM

Tags: c++, ios

I am getting an error.

One of the source files references:

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
```

I am working with a Makefile below, trying to link:

```
LDFLAGS =-l../../usr/local/sys/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib
```

Path appears to be correct, and the file is there.

Error details from IDE:
http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1333837472-clip-29kb.png
http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1333837744-clip-32kb.png

What am I doing wrong?

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for iPhone application (X)
#############################################################################

# Define here the name of your project's main executable, and the name of the
# build directory where the generated binaries and resources will go.
NAME    = X
OUTDIR  = X.app

# Define here the minimal iOS version's MAJOR number (iOS3, iOS4 or iOS5)
IOSMINVER = 5

# List here your project's resource files. They can be files or directories.
RES = Info.plist icon.png

# Define here the compile options and the linker options for your project.
CFLAGS  = -W -Wall -O2 -Icocos2dx/include -Icocos2dx/platform -Icocos2dx/platform/ios -Icocos2dx/effects -Icocos2dx/cocoa -Icocos2dx/support -Icocos2dx/support/image_support -Icocos2dx/support/data_support -Icocos2dx/support/zip_support -Icocos2dx/extensions -Icocos2dx
LDFLAGS =-l../../usr/local/sys/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib

#############################################################################
# Except for specific projects, you shouldn't need to change anything below
#############################################################################

# Define which compiler to use and what are the mandatory compiler and linker
# options to build stuff for iOS. Here, use the ARM cross-compiler for iOS,
# define IPHONE globally and link against all available frameworks.
CC  = clang
LD  = link
CFLAGS  += -ccc-host-triple arm-apple-darwin -march=armv6 --sysroot ../../usr/local/sys -integrated-as -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -fconstant-cfstrings -DIPHONE -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=$(IOSMINVER)0000
LDFLAGS += -lstdc++ $(addprefix -framework , $(notdir $(basename $(wildcard /Frameworks/iOS$(IOSMINVER)/*))))

# List here your source files. The current rule means: ask the shell to build
# a one-liner list of all files in the current directory and its subdirectories
# ending with either .c, .cc, .cpp, .cxx, .m, .mm, .mx or .mxx.
SRC = $(shell find . \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.m" -o -name "*.mm" -o -name "*.mx" -o -name "*.mxx" \) -printf '%p ')

# Define where the object files should go - currently, just aside the source
# files themselves. We take the source file's basename and just append .o.
OBJ = $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRC)))

###################
# Rules definitions

# This rule is the default rule that is called when you type "make". It runs
# the specified other rules in that order: removing generated output from
# previous builds, compiling all source files into object files, linking them
# all together, codesigning the generated file, copying resources in place
# and then displaying a success message.
all:    prune $(OBJ) link codesign resources checksum ipa deb end

# The following rule removes the generated output from any previous builds
prune:
    @echo " + Pruning compilation results..."
    @rm -f $(OUTDIR)/$(NAME)

# The following rules compile any .c/.cc/.cpp/.cxx/.m/.mm/.mx/.mxx file it
# finds in object files (.o). This is to handle source files in different
# languages: C/C++ (with .c* extension), and Objective-C (.m*).
%.o:    %.c
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:    %.cc
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:    %.cpp
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:    %.cxx
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:    %.m
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:    %.mm
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:    %.mx
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:    %.mxx
    @echo " + Compiling $<..."; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# The following rule first ensures the output directory exists, creates it if
# necessary, then links the compiled .o files together in that directory
link:
    @echo " + Linking project files..."
    @test -d $(OUTDIR) || mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)
    @$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OUTDIR)/$(NAME) $(OBJ)

# The following rule calls Saurik's ldid code pseudo-signing tool to generate
# the SHA checksums needed for the generated binary to run on jailbroken iOS.
codesign:
    @echo " + Pseudo-signing code..."
    @ldid -S $(OUTDIR)/$(NAME)
    @rm -f $(OUTDIR)/.$(NAME).cs

# The following rule takes all the specified resource items one after the
# other (whether they are files or directories) ; files are copied in place
# and directories are recursively copied only if they don't exist already.
resources:
    @echo " + Copying resources..."
    @for item in $(RES); do \
        if [ -d $$item ]; then test -d $(OUTDIR)/$$item || cp -r $$item $(OUTDIR)/; chmod +r $(OUTDIR)/$$item; \
        else cp $$item $(OUTDIR)/; chmod +r $(OUTDIR)/$$item; \
        fi; \
    done
    @chmod +x $(OUTDIR)
    @chmod -R +r $(OUTDIR)
    @chmod +x $(OUTDIR)/$(NAME)

# The following rule takes all files in the target directory and builds the
# _CodeSignature/CodeResource XML file with their SHA1 hashes.
checksum:
    @echo " + Generating _CodeSignature directory..."
    @echo -n APPL???? > $(OUTDIR)/PkgInfo
    @codesigner $(OUTDIR) > .CodeResources.$(NAME)
    @test -d $(OUTDIR)/_CodeSignature || mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)/_CodeSignature
    @mv .CodeResources.$(NAME) $(OUTDIR)/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
    @test -L $(OUTDIR)/CodeResources || ln -s _CodeSignature/CodeResources $(OUTDIR)/CodeResources

# The following rule builds an IPA file out of the compiled app directory.
ipa:
    @echo " + Building iTunes package..."
    @test -d Packages || mkdir Packages
    @rm -f Packages/$(NAME).ipa
    @test -d Payload || mkdir Payload
    @mv -f $(OUTDIR) Payload
    @cp -f iTunesArtwork.jpg iTunesArtwork
    @chmod +r iTunesArtwork
    @zip -y -r Packages/$(NAME).ipa Payload iTunesArtwork -x \*.log \*.lastbuildstate \*successfulbuild > /dev/null
    @rm -f iTunesArtwork
    @mv -f Payload/$(OUTDIR) .
    @rmdir Payload

# The following rule builds a Cydia package out of the compiled app directory.
deb:
    @echo " + Building Cydia package..."
    @test -d Packages || mkdir Packages
    @rm -f Packages/$(NAME).deb
    @test -d $(NAME) || mkdir $(NAME)
    @test -d $(NAME)/Applications || mkdir $(NAME)/Applications
    @mv -f $(OUTDIR) $(NAME)/Applications
    @test -d $(NAME)/DEBIAN || mkdir $(NAME)/DEBIAN
    @cp -f cydia-package.cfg $(NAME)/DEBIAN/control
    @chmod +r $(NAME)/DEBIAN/control
    @echo "#!/bin/bash" > $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @echo "rm -f /Applications/$(OUTDIR)/*.log /Applications/$(OUTDIR)/*.lastbuildstate /Applications/$(OUTDIR)/*.successfulbuild" >> $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @echo "chown -R root:admin \"/Applications/$(OUTDIR)\"" >> $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @echo "find \"/Applications/$(OUTDIR)\"|while read ITEM; do if [ -d \"\$$ITEM\" ]; then chmod 755 \"\$$ITEM\"; else chmod 644 \"\$$ITEM\"; fi; done" >> $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @echo "chmod +x \"/Applications/$(OUTDIR)/$(NAME)\"" >> $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @echo "su -c /usr/bin/uicache mobile 2> /dev/null" >> $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @echo "exit 0" >> $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @chmod +r+x $(NAME)/DEBIAN/postinst
    @dpkg-deb -b $(NAME) > /dev/null 2>&1
    @mv -f $(NAME).deb Packages
    @mv -f $(NAME)/Applications/$(OUTDIR) .
    @rm -rf $(NAME)

# This simple rule displays the success message after a successful build
end:
    @echo " + Done. Output directory is \"$(OUTDIR)\", iTunes package is \"Packages\$(NAME).ipa\", Cydia package is \"Packages\$(NAME).deb\"."

# This rule removes generated object files from the project and also temporary
# files ending with ~ or #.
clean:
    @echo " + Cleaning project intermediate files..."
    @rm -f $(OBJ) *~ *\#
    @echo " + Done."

# This rule removes all generated output from any previous builds so as to
# leave an intact source tree (useful for generating source tree releases).
distclean: clean
    @echo " + Cleaning project output files..."
    @rm -rf $(OUTDIR)
    @echo " + Done."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually may have two problems. I suggest you try:

Add `-I../../usr/local/sys/usr/include` to your CFLAGS to make it find the header.

Change the `LDFLAGS` to `-L../../usr/local/sys/usr/lib`, add `LIBS=-lxml2` and change the linker invocation to `$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OUTDIR)/$(NAME) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)` (i.e. add the `-l` at the end, the `-L` at the beginning of the linker command line).

Comment: Daniel, thanks for an answer. But still same problem.
Am i doing what you suggested correctly?
http://pastebin.com/Nu5VCHKE

Comment: Does `../../usr/local/sys/usr/include` contain a `libxml` directory containing a `parser.h` file? Do you have a `parser.h` file somewhere? You might to point the `-I` to some subdirectory of `include` depending on how libxml2 is installed there.

Answer (score 3):

-l is for specifying the library name only. Use -L to add directories where libraries will also be looked for:

```
LDFLAGS += -L../../usr/local/sys/usr/lib -lxml2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. But still same result:
http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1333840844-clip-29kb.png

Comment: @private describe your problem in the question, not with links to other websites

Comment: Sure, i am trying to link libxml because one of my .ccp files includes it. None of the suggestions so far work. When it tries to compile the .cpp it cannot find the libxml/parser.h which is specified in the LDFLAGS of the Makefile running against clang.

error : 'libxml/parser.h' file not found

Comment: again, put this information in your question. Stackoverflow isn't a discussion forum.