# Correct way to load libxml via Makefile when compiling for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, makefile

I have a .cpp that includes libxml headers

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
```

What is a correct way of loading libxml via Makefile when compiling under clang/llvm?

```
LDFLAGS = -L../../usr/local/sys/usr/lib -lxml2
```

results in:
    error : 'libxml/parser.h' file not found
during compilation

Environment is iosdevenv under windows7 (so directory structure is different than on mac os)

Comment: possible duplicate of [linking .dylib via LDFLAGS using clang/LLVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058939/linking-dylib-via-ldflags-using-clang-llvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're providing `-I path_to_wherever_the_libxml_headers_are` to the compiler.